# Why from c# mail want to send picture (signature) in body?

Tags: c#, sendmail, image

I would like to send mail with a picture inside the email body. In my first attempts, the picture appears like an attachment: it is visible but at the end. I need the picture to be at the center of the email body.

The tutorial which I used is [link](http://blog.devexperience.net/en/12/Send_an_Email_in_CSharp_with_Inline_attachments.aspx).

My code looks like this:

```
    mail.Body = "string htmlBody = \"<html><body><h1><center><img src=\"C:\\picture.png\"/></h1></html>";
    string contentID = "image1";
    Attachment inline = new Attachment("C:\\picture.png");
    inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
    inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
    inline.ContentId = contentID;
    inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
    inline.ContentType.Name = "C:\\picture.png";
    mail.Attachments.Add(inline);
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd really have followed the tutorial, you'd have seen this code:

```
email.Body = "[...]<img src=\"@@IMAGE@@\" alt=\"\">";

// generate the contentID string using the datetime
string contentID = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath).Replace(".", "");

Attachment inline
[...]
inline.ContentId = contentID;
[...]
email.Attachments.Add(inline);

// replace the tag with the correct content ID
email.Body = email.Body.Replace("@@IMAGE@@", "cid:" + contentID);
```

Of course using `<img src="C:\picture.png">` won't work, since the user that receives the mail most probably won't have that image in that path on their PC, let alone when they're using webmail.

Comment: @IvanPericic it should. "Don't work" isn't anything anyone can work with, please update your question with **what exactly happens** if you use the code given in the example.

Comment: It's seems that in this code it use encryption and my code doesnt work cause i didn't encrypt it. I'm using gmail smtp,  this example is for sending mails from localhost.

Comment: @IvanPericic this has nothing to do with encryption. If you want to inline an image in an email, you have to use the content ID in the HTML to refer to the inlined image. You have to set the ContentID on the attachment too, so your client knows what resource you're referring to.